# Python run JavaScript 3.8

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I have node.js installed and want to know if there is any way to run js code on **python 3.8**. I need to use a large piece of code (babylon) for my web application. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Running Code

I admit I have not messed with this before, but I think the best way to go about it is to have a js file that you can run from python. I found 2 ways to accomplish this- one that returns output and one that simply just runs it.

### Getting Output

You may be able to use the `subprocess` module to run the node and record it's output for later use.

```
import subprocess
myValue = subprocess.check_output(['node','index.js'])
```

[Python `subprocess.check_output` Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.check_output)

### No Output

If you do not require to read the output of the file, you can just run it with the `os` module.

```
import os
os.system("node index.js")
```

[Python `os.system` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.check_output)

Answer (score 0):

I do like the answer given. I would like to add that one could use the Naked library:

```py
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js
execute_js('file.js')
```

One can read more here: https://naked.readthedocs.io/